# Jasper report with subreport using jsonql as datasource getting JRExpressionEvalException error

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I had a very difficult time figuring out how to properly create a subreport using jasper reports with a jsonql datasource, so I hope it will help anybody who may encounter the same trouble.

I was getting `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. use the `dataSourceExpression`:

`<subreport>(... other nodes)<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("myList")]]></dataSourceExpression></subreport>`

2. This `"myList"` argument is the intern node that will be the `Detail` of the subreport! In the subreport jrxml file set the detail loop to be exactly where the subnode you passed is, on the `Dataset and Query Dialog` screen, ex: `outerNode.outerNodeOther.myList`
3. I did not need to pass parameters!
4. The takeway is that all tutorials I had found used `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource` instead of `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource` when setting up the `<dataSourceExpression>` configuration inside the `dataSourceExpression` of the main report jrxml file!

I hope this will save you time!

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are for posting and answering your own "question" but that note about JsonDataSource vs JsonQLDataSource ultimately brought an end to a months-long problem I was having.

My reports were failing because of that one expression, and removing the "QL" removed the failure, but delivered a blank report. 

Turns out I'd been trying to compile a Report using the "json" driver, when I needed to be using the "jsonql" driver.